# why use javascript routing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, backbone.js, url-routing

There seem to be many libraries and packages (Crossroads.js, etc.) which support this javascript routing functionality, but I'm having trouble understanding a scenario where this is valuable.

Anyone care to go soup-to-nuts on situations where this is useful?

My background is with ASP.NET (web forms) programming and some amateur javascript/jquery.

Comment: Are you talking about line-routing in a diagram?

Comment: no, more along the lines of the functionality you get with a package like Crossroads.js.

Comment: Javascript is evolving a lot nowadays, there are a lot of trends about making it more confortable on large-scale, as it is not. There will be solid patterns and best practices, but things like crossroads.js are pioneers on new grounds. Ingenious pioneers.

Answer (score 5):

It gives you option to handle client behavior without having to reload whole page as if with cases when you'd be handling routing server side.

It opens up possibilities for way more responsive and interactive designs as instead of reloading whole page each time route changes you are able to rerender only the portion of the website that changs for a given route. At the same time it helps reducing the load on the server as you reduce the client server communication to sending only the data required to display a page for client to handle it (render views etc.)

Thanks to using backbone.js or other mvc(-like) frameworks you are able to reduce your server to expose just the REST API for working with and receiving data without having to handle the rendering and you are passing some - or even most at times - of the logic to the client.

Most of the web apps nowadays are taking advantage of client-side routing - anything from GMail to twitter.

Comment: can you give a specific example?  what are the benefits over a scenario where I have a single page app and each major section has some ajax endpoint exposed on the server which refreshes the corresponding page section with the appropriate content?

Comment: Having proper routing rather then ajax callbacks scattered here or there means it's much easier and more elegant for the user as for him  it's still the good old internet with its clean URL addresses that they can bookmark, copy and paste to docs, friends etc. and easily access the given state of the page/app by just visiting the address.

Users are getting used to more and more interactive and seamless experiences and browsers are getting more then fast enough to deliver these.

Comment: It's just a step forward from ajax heavy applications and adaptation of best practices we've learned from the server side development and their MVC frameworks. (didn't fit :) )

Comment: thanks.  regarding "Having proper routing rather then ajax callbacks scattered here or there means it's much easier and more elegant for the user...": how is it better?  can you give a concrete example?

Comment: In the end - if you achieve the same result by updating the app URL in the browser's address bar, and will make it possible to access all the states of the app with these custom urls - from user's perspective it's as good as routing cause it achieves the same. BUT! It's more verbose, more maintainable and cleaner to add handling for new routes/paths in the app then tailoring in support for handling extra pages in some kind of ajax solution without a router.

Comment: thanks for your efforts- it seems you are giving me the conclusions to an argument which, to me, is best established by some *specific* scenario or example which compares an implementation involving client side routing with one that doesn't.  that is really what I'd like to see... then perhaps your comments will come into better focus for me.  I need a concrete, specific example.  Code or pseudocode, html, etc.

Comment: is Gmail good enough example?
- applying a filter - changing route (thanks to that we can access filters by altering url in address bar or bookmarking filter state and accessing it quickly). Let's have another one - twitter - tweets are accessed with routing as well - thanks to using routes - if you want to give somebody quick access to this tweet - you just copy url and send it via email/facebook/whatnot

Comment: Also I forgot to add one more important feature - using routing makes it possible to take advantage of browser history - so user can move between app states using history back/forward etc. Don't think i can come up with better examples or explain it better - sorry

Answer (score 1):

OK- I think I understand it better now.  It's just a layer of abstraction between a function caller and callee.  Instead of attaching a hardcoded dependency between the caller and callee, you can introduce a routing system which will connect the two based on some configuration and provide additional functions like validation, or binding multiple callees to a caller.  Then you can reference your actions with restful handles (eg "/getCoffee/decaf") which can also be dynamically constructed (since they're just strings).

I'm still pondering the relative benefits of a routing scheme vs creating a custom event.